# Combining multiple lines into one single line

Tags: java, file, replace, io, bufferedreader

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
thiasisatest("test1", 
        "test2", 
        "test3", 
        "test4", 
        "test5");
```

The output I am trying to achieve is this:

```
thiasisatest("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5");
```

My code looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class IoTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Applications/textfile.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(sCurrentLine.trim().replace("\n", ""));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I am reading the line and replacing all lines in the while loop, but the output doesn't change and the lines are still there when I am trying to print out the string.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help

Comment: USE System.out.print():

Comment: as a future tip, instead of \n use System.lineSeparator(). That guarantees independence from operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually do not need to replace the line; Because you are technically recalling line by line.

All you need to do is create a StringBuilder to which you append every line from your buffered reader.

Your code should look like this

```
String sCurrentLine;

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
    builder.append(sCurrentLine);
}
```

You can now output the content of the "builder" to another file.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println
```

terminates the line, that it why you are getting multiple lines.

Comment: Is this really correct? The output is still the same if I use "System.out.print", and removing the replace function..

Comment: why are you removing the replace function? that will keep the "\n" characters and reinsert the multiple lines.